# Cannot locate my deployed files in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am pretty new to Firebase Cloud Functions, and am trying to write a URL rewriter of sorts, but I cannot for the life of me work out where my files are.

The emulator doesn't look amazing, so I am making changes locally and deploying them with logging. It is not at all clear where my files are.

My function looks like this:

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "dist", "assets")));

exports.jambudipaApp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  functions.logger.info(`__dirname = ${__dirname}`);
  const folders1 = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, ".."));
  functions.logger.info(`Folders in ${path.join(__dirname, "..")}: ${folders1}`);

  const folders2 = fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
  functions.logger.info(`Folders in ${__dirname}: ${folders2}`);

  if (req.headers.host === "<subdomain, handled elsewhere>") {
    return app(req, res);
  } else {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "dist", "public", "index.html"));
  }
});
```

(I've been hacking around with this all day, so apologies if it's messy)

My files are locally is `dist`, having been generated by `vite`. My `firebase.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

This config has worked with other sites without Cloud Functions, so I'm pretty certain the files are being copied correctly. but those logs above yields these results in the log explorer:

> __dirname = /workspace

> Folders in /: bin,boot,cloudsql,cnb,config,dev,dev,etc,home,layers,lib,lib64,media,mnt,opt,proc,proc,root,run,sbin,serve,srv,start,sys,sys,tmp,tmp,usr,var,workspace,www-data-home

> Folders in /workspace: .gitignore,.googlebuild,.runtimeconfig.json,index.js,node_modules,package-lock.json,package.json

No `dist` and no `public` in either of those. What gives?

UPDATE

Not sure what is going on:

```
functions.logger.info(`Requesting index.html from ${path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html")}`);
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
```

Gives this error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/workspace/public/index.html'

Although if I navigate to `https://example.com/public/index.html` directly, it does serve it. So I am not convinced I am addressing the folder correctly.

*What is the correct way to get the folder where my files are stored?*

This URL works: `https://example.com/public/index.html`
This does not: `https://example.com`

I have tried both `path.join()` and `path.resolve()`: the latter gives a Firebase error, the former a 404.

Comment: With the updated answer it looks like you mix `functions` with `hosting`. If `vite` is used in a classical compilation without Server Side Rendering, then only assets (.js, .html, .css) files will be uploaded for Static content hosting in Firebase (CDN). `Function` is absolutely different subproject that is run for requests computation (kind of mini server, AWS lambda analogue). `functions` cannot access local `hosting` folders. Does it help?

Comment: Well the function is executing on the server, and since they provide an https function, I would expect the files to be available. I am going to read the documentation for that, since until now I have relying upon ChatGPT! Thanks Artur 

Comment: Functions don't execute on "the server".  They are any number of server instances that can come and go according to the actual load on the function.  These server instances are completely disconnected from Firebase Hosting, which is actually served via a third party service called Fastly.  You can't just reach into Firebase Hosting content from Functions and change them on the fly. What Firebase Hosting does do for you is redirect some of your requests to Functions if you want, but at that point the code is still running outside of Fastly completely and on those server instances I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying "dist" path for deployment:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
  }
}
```

means that all the content from "./dist" folder relative to your local project will be deployed.

That `dist` folder becomes the `root` folder for your remote instance. If you have `dist/assets/my.jpg` image, create a file `dist/index.js` with the next content:

```
const pathToImage = path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/my.jpg');
```

Comment: I have added an update...could you take a look?