# Firebase hosting: What is the procedure for serving different index.html files based on domain name?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75978393/cannot-locate-my-deployed-files-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase), but was unable to resolve the issue; so I'm taking a step back.

If I have two different `index.html` files – one for https://myexample.com and another for https://sub.myexample.com – what is the procedure for configuring Firebase hosting to support this?

I had asked ChatGPT which gave me some Cloud Function and `firebase.json` but it does not work; the uploaded files do not appear to be available in the Cloud Function.

An alternative question might be: how do I get access to the folders uploaded by `firebase deploy` in my Cloud Function so I can do a URL rewrite?

Comment: Your second question seems unrelated to the first.  ChatGPT is leading you the wrong way with Cloud Functions.  If you want two different sites hosting with Firebase Hosting with different content, then they should simply be different deployments altogether.  The sites can't really share a single deployment of files, even if they are mostly the same stuff.  Two sites with different content requires two projects with separate deployments.

Comment: If you just want the root of the site to be served differently by Functions, then you will have to put the code of that HTML into the Function deployment (not deployed to Hosting) and have the code decide which HTML to output based on the incoming request.  It's not just a simple configuration switch.

Comment: They are related, if you follow the link to the other question you will see a fragment of the suggested implementation. Perhaps you’re right, but I have emailed Google Firebase support and will let you know what they say.

Comment: No I know it’s not a configuration switch. Do you know if it’s possible to access the hosted files within a Cloud Function? If so, then problem solved, since the rest of it was working.

Comment: If you really want to do that, then make an HTTP request for them from the function like any other HTTP request. Otherwise, no - I've been trying to explain your alternative. The code in the other question is not accessing Hosting at all.  It's accessing files that were deployed with the function  deployment, which is not at all related to a Hosting deployment.  Completely different things deployed in a different way to different destinations.

Comment: Ok, it's sinking in. The deployed files aren't available in Cloud Functions, and if I want to do it the way I have in mind, it would mean fetching the file then sending it. If you were asked how, then, code that is common to many sites could be shared without having to download it again for each site, what would be your response? Since that is the reason I am attempting to do it in this way? Maybe cacheing in a worker on the client or something of that nature? I'm not particularly attached to the approach I outlined in my question, but avoiding download duplication is what I'm after really.